# asp.net code quality check it

Tags: asp.net

hello  Friends please verify my code 
Is it a right way to pass optional parameter to a method.
if any thing wrong please suggest me if there exist any better solution.

```
protected void Ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                int course_id = Convert.ToInt32(course.SelectedValue);
                int passoutYear = Convert.ToInt32(passout.SelectedValue);
                int currentBacklog = Convert.ToInt32(currrentBacklogDDL.SelectedValue);
                int sex = Convert.ToInt32(gender.SelectedValue);
                int? eGap = null;
                int? firstYrPercent = null;
                int? secondYrPercent = null;
                int? thirdYrPercent = null;
                int? finalYearpercent = null;
                int? currentDegeePercentage = null;
                int? highSchoolPercentge = null;
                int? higherSchoolPercentage = null;
                int? grauationPercentage = null;
                int? diplomaPercentage = null;
                int? noOfAtkt = null;

                string dateOfBirth = DOB.Text.Trim();
                DateTime birthDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateOfBirth, "dd/mm/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string outPut = birthDate.ToString("mm/dd/YYYY");
                DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(outPut);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(educationGap.Text))
                {
                    eGap = Convert.ToInt32(educationGap.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstYear.Text))
                {
                    firstYrPercent = Convert.ToInt32(firstYear.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondYear.Text))
                {
                    secondYrPercent = Convert.ToInt32(secondYear.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(thirdYear.Text))
                {
                    thirdYrPercent = Convert.ToInt32(thirdYear.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(finalyear.Text))
                {
                    finalYearpercent = Convert.ToInt32(finalyear.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentDegree.Text))
                {
                    currentDegeePercentage = Convert.ToInt32(currentDegree);
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(higherSchool.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    higherSchoolPercentage = Convert.ToInt32(higherSchool.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(highSchool.Text))
                {
                    highSchoolPercentge = Convert.ToInt32(highSchool.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(graduation.Text))
                {
                    grauationPercentage = Convert.ToInt32(graduation.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(diploma.Text))
                {
                    diplomaPercentage = Convert.ToInt32(diploma.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(atkt.Text))
                {
                    noOfAtkt = Convert.ToInt32(atkt.Text.Trim());
                }

                Dictionary<string, object> paramList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                paramList.Add("@courseId", course_id);
                paramList.Add("@passoutYear", passoutYear);
                paramList.Add("@currentBacklog", currentBacklog);
                paramList.Add("@sex", sex);
                paramList.Add("@eGap", eGap);
                paramList.Add("@firstYrPercent", firstYrPercent);
                paramList.Add("@secondYrPercent", secondYrPercent);
                paramList.Add("@thirdYrPercent", thirdYrPercent);
                paramList.Add("@finalYearpercent", finalYearpercent);
                paramList.Add("@currentDegeePercentage", currentDegeePercentage);
                paramList.Add("@highSchoolPercentge", highSchoolPercentge);
                paramList.Add("@higherSchoolPercentage", higherSchoolPercentage);
                paramList.Add("@grauationPercentage", grauationPercentage);
                paramList.Add("@diplomaPercentage", diplomaPercentage);
                paramList.Add("@noOfAtkt", noOfAtkt);

                StringBuilder branchId= new StringBuilder();
                foreach (ListItem li in branch.Items)
                {
                    if (li.Selected)
                    {
                        branchId.Append(Convert.ToInt32(li.Value));
                    }
                }
                DataTable dt = searchManager.GetEligibleStudent(paramList, branchId);



            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            COMMON.logger.Error("Error On Button click Ok", ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bit sad that you first convert the values to the correct value, then put it into a list of object such that in GetEligibleStudent, you'll have to cast those values again.

My guess would be to create a class for this, such that, say, higherSchoolPercentage becomes a field. Since you'll be getting student records back, it might even be that you can reuse this structure.

hth,
Nic

**UPDATE**

create a class like

```
class StudentQuery
{
    public int course_id;
    ...
    public int? egap = null;
    ...   

}
```

then, in your page, say

```
StudentQuery sq = new StudentQuery();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(educationGap.Text))
{
    sq.eGap = Convert.ToInt32(educationGap.Text.Trim());
}
```

Then you can say

```
DataTable dt = searchManager.GetEligibleStudent(sq, branchId);
```

Like this,

- you keep the type of the variables
- you don't have to create this paramList
- the separation between problem structure (which fields you got) and data (which values the fields have) is clearer.

**UPDATE 2**

Since the only format in which these fields are required is, in fact, the key/value list that's built here, to be passed on to an SQL command, I think the code sample is ok. One might still think about refactoring that code into a separate method, but my previous suggestion of creating a class turns out to be, in fact, superfluous.

Comment: I appologise sir but i am not getting you,
i am passing this to method parameteers to call a mehod of business logic class where i will get the datatable by writing appropriate query to get the data table
like here

Comment: public DataTable GetEligibleStudent(Dictionary<string, object> paramList, StringBuilder branchId)
    {
        try
        {
            string cmd = "";
            //string cmd = "SELECT * FROM [tbl_branch] WHERE course_id IN(" + sb + ")";
            if (dbManager.OpenConnection())
            {
                dt = dbManager.GetDataTable(cmd, paramList);
                return dt;
            }
            else
            {
                dt = null;
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: how can i edit the above code it limits me to put the characters and i don't know how to edit it also please let me know

Comment: yea formatting in comments isn't possible. Only way is to update your question. So I made in update in my answer. Basically I'm saying separate your business logic (which fields there *are* at all) from the contents, by "hardwiring" the possible fields into a class.

Comment: but sir what is the benifit of this it seems to be same task, you mean to say that i should make a separate class where i should define variables and there value should be set here then i sould paas the object of that class then object dot property i can access the values 
but i dont need to again add it like key value pair so that i can uese @variable name to protect it from sql injection

Comment: ok I see what you're trying to achieve here. Don't you need a proper list of OleDbParameters for sql injection protection? What type is dbManager?

Comment: sir dbManager is what type meaning?
sir always added parameter by putting @variable so i can achieve this or i will have to re-add all these parameter to dictionary in key value form to make variable with @variable name

Comment: you write dt = dbManager.GetDataTable() - I'm just wondering where dbManager comes from, it's not declared in your sample. Ie, what class of object (that's what I mean with "which type")

Comment: see i am following 3 layer archtecture 1st is presentation layer where i have written all this code mentioned above then business logic layer where i will pass these parameter to interact with this class and dbmanaer is actually object of database class the third final layer please explain me ahead

Comment: this dbManger is the object of database class where the cmd sql query will be passed t get the result

Comment: is this a class from yourself? the point is: I don't think the key/value collection you set up is going to really protect you from SQL injection. But maybe I'm wrong. If I am wrong, your proposed approach is correct. But it's hard to tell without knowing what dbManager does exactly. Is it a standard .NET class or something custom-built?

Comment: public DataTable GetDataTable(string strCmd, Dictionary<string, object> paramList)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, _sqlCon);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in paramList)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("Error when executing Query " + strCmd,

Comment: the above s hte method written in that

Comment: i suppose nw you have understood all of cod flow now please let me know what is the best solution either to geter setter or my code is also good ....should i do explained by u above

Comment: i am waiting 4 your reply so that i can proceed ahead:)

Comment: Ok that looks safe. So yea, actually, if you're never going to use that data structure again, and since you need that kind of list anyway, I think it's good like that!

Comment: ok nice you took something from it even you were right from the beginning :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do all that validating and converting in a loop.

Comment: please elaborate me sir on this i am no getting.
All validation are done by using validators

Answer (score 0):

I feel if you write normal data bean which is having getters and setters then will be more better than this....

Comment: I think what he means by a data bean is a lot like what I propose (although a bean would have to be a bit stricter in terms of public variables vs proper getter and setter functions ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use that search method in other places you should use a *struct* or a *class* for your parameters.  That way you can keep type safety in your method.

Currently you'd have to write extra code to test the types passed for each key in your dictionary.  You would not have to do that if you had a class since the members all have types.

It's really programming style.  Some developers like to maintain type safety unless they absolutely can't anymore.  Others like to keep the compiler out of their business.  C# as a language tries to appeal to both groups.  Originally it was a strictly a statically typed language but now we have dynamic / duck typing.